# Why would an Acumatica API action work correctly in Postman, but not work in .NET (although it reports success)?

Tags: acumatica

I'm calling the Shipment/ConfirmShipment endpoint, and it's returning success in both .NET and Postman, but using Postman the shipment actually gets confirmed, while in .NET it doesn't.

In Postman, I'm doing a POST with the body containing JSON for the shipment number:

```
{"entity":{"ShipmentNbr":{"value":"022025"}}}
```

In .NET, I'm doing a HttpClient.PostAsync() to the same URL and with the same JSON as above. They both return success with a 202 Accepted response. However, as I mentioned, the Postman call confirms the shipment (Confirm = 1, Status = F), but in .NET, the POST doesn't actually confirm the shipment. Any ideas of what might be preventing it?

API v17.200.001

Comment: I would suggest using Fiddler to look at the traffic happening between your machine and Acumatica. You’ll likely identify a subtle difference in your HTTP calls between .NET and Postman.

Comment: Gabriel, that sounded like a good idea, but when I do that, Fiddler doesn't show anything for my .NET POST.  Unless there's a way to configure it to do so?

Comment: I did find that there's ways to configure Fiddler to see HttpClient calls, but I decided to not take it any further since I discovered the issue to be unrelated.

Comment: If you discovered the answer please create an short answer and accept it so that if someone else encounters a similar issue they can benefit from this question as well

Answer (score 2):

The status 202 Accepted might be a bit confusing but it does not mean that the action has completed succefully.

It only means that the execution request is valid and has been accepted by the system.

If you want to monitor the status of the Action itself you will need to use the address given in the header of the 202 Accepted response (the Location header)

So in my example that follows, you can see that my action has been accepted and that when I request the status of the operation I then get the 204 No Content which is the Success response.

Here I have requested the execution of the Confirm Shipment action and it has been accepted and I can see the url where I can fetch the status of the action

[image]

Here I have requested the status of the the action and can see the successful result
[image]

You can find more information here about the execution of an action through the REST API.

I recommend taking a look at the response section.

- https://help-2017r2.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=91bf9106-062a-47a8-be1f-b48517a54324

Here is more information about the 202 and the 204 http response:

- https://httpstatuses.com/202
- https://httpstatuses.com/204

Comment: Thank you for including all of this info, but the HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode also returns true.  I went ahead and tried your suggestion also, but it also returns success.  After further debugging, I discovered this issue actually had to do more with a timing issue than the actual API call in my .NET code.  After that was resolved, the API calls started working.